# Excel: Return value blank and i want to keep it blank or empty

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

To keep it short i have this if IF statement:

```
=IF(AND(MOD(Sheet1!AY9,1)>TIMEVALUE("11:00"),MOD(Sheet1!AY9,1)<TIMEVALUE("11:59")),sheet2!D8,Sheet1!W5)
```

the return of sheet2!D8 some time is 0 and some time is empty but it convert the empty to 0. My issue is when returns empty i want it to be empty not 0.

thanks for helping

Comment: Add an if statement to check if sheet2!D8 is empty, if it is true then leave it blank "" otherwise return the sheet2!D8 cell value: =IF(AND(MOD(Sheet1!AY9,1)>TIMEVALUE("11:00"),MOD(Sheet1!AY9,1)<TIMEVALUE("11:59")),if(sheet2!D8="","",sheet2!D8),Sheet1!W5)

Comment: Do you want it blank because of the calculations or you do not want to display zero values? What is output for `False`?